# Faster way for overwriting data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I have to figure out the faster way for overwriting data.

Constraints of this operation are both resource utilization and time.

The approaches are listed below:

```
1. Delete all documents in index completely, then insert new documents
2. Delete index, recreate index, insert documents
```

I will appreciate your opinion.

Comment: What is the use case for this?  If you need a seamless transition between sets of data, why not use an alias?

Comment: After reading your comment I have read about index aliases but I am still not sure how to do a seamless transition between sets using them , could you tell me more about your idea?

Comment: @Dennis are you talking about this?   https://books.google.com/books?id=d19aBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA151&lpg=&source=bl&ots=Nzi-oPyyiI&sig=ACfU3U3B9zhiTyulwbxVUVzpmr2EBAZQWQ&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNrpSnycTkAhVHLKwKHUhQDXMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for option 2. Deleting all docs has a lot more overhead than simply dropping the entire index.